# How to keep the same locale throughout the pages until user puts another command in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, locale

I'm trying to make users to see same locale throughout the pages unless the user changes again.

I thought I solved this issue by using global variable $language to temporarily save user's command. User request locale change by using url_for(:locale => 'kr')

It works if there is no user except me. But once the user comes in and they change the configuration, my configuration is also updated because $language is shared. How would I be able to prevent this thing from occuring? (:

Please give me any hunch in Ruby!!

#### View

```
<%= link_to 'Korean', url_for( :locale => 'kr') ,{:style=>"padding-top:0px;"} %>
<%= link_to 'English', url_for( :locale => 'en') ,{:style=>"padding-top:0px;"} %>
```

#### Application.rb

```
$language = "kr"

def default_url_options(options = {})
    { locale: I18n.locale }.merge options
  end

  def set_locale

    if params[:locale] 
      locale_save = params[:locale]
    else
      locale_save = $language 
    end

    I18n.locale = locale_save || params[:locale] || "kr"
    if params[:locale]
      $language = params[:locale]
    end
    @locale = $language

  end
```

### #

Comment: Per-user settings/data should be stored in the session. (That's an over-simplification, but the point is that global variables are just that: global.)

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, `$language` is completely global to the Ruby process, so setting it affects every user hitting the server. If you ever have multiple servers, you'll run into a different problem where you set `$language` on one, but the others don't hear about it, so depending which server you hit, you'll get whichever locale was last set on it.

Since this is a per-user setting, you want to put it on the `session`. (If you have some `User` model in your database and want to save the setting across logins / clearing cookies, you could also put it there). You should more or less be able to replace your use of `$language` with something like `session[:locale]`:

```
session[:locale] = params[:locale] || session[:locale] || 'kr'
I18n.locale = @locale = session[:locale]
```

The first line sets the locale in order of precedence:

- If there's a `locale` parameter, use it and save it
- Otherwise, use what's already in the `session`
- Finally, default to `kr`

Once that decision is made, the second line sets `I18n` and `@locale` for the rest of your program. Depending how `@locale` is used, you probably don't actually need that and can just use `session[:locale]` everywhere instead.